# Passive Voice vs. Active Voice, or not?

Tags: active-voice

I am wondering which of the following sentence is grammarly correct, and why?
Your specific answer will be of great help!

1. In fact, Beijing's hutongs* are in different width ranging from 40 centimeters to 10 meters.
2. In fact, Beijing's hutongs* are in different width ranged from 40 centimeters to 10 meters.

*Hutong is something like alley.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: ...ranging **between** 40 cm **and** 10 m in *width*. Neither example in your post are in the passive voice, the first uses the gerund (ranging) while the second is the past participle (ranged) form.

Comment: And you need **widths** (plural).

Comment: I would use '**of** different widths'.

Comment: Beijing's hutongs range from 40 centimeters to 10 meters in width.